# Recents in Finder doesn't show any files on my M1 Macbook Air running Monterey

Tags: macos, finder, monterey

I switched to a new Macbook Air M1 with Monterey. The Finder window's Recents doesn't show any files though I have just downloaded a few files, opened one, and edit-saved another too.

[image: Finder's Recents is empty]

When using my browsers (Safari / FF) and selecting files for upload, the Finder window that popsup also doesn't show recent files. What may be the issue?

Is there somewhere in the OS I can tweak what the default "Recents" shows in my Finder window? Am able to create a search, name it "Recent Files" and add it to Finder sidebar but the default recents macOS provides fails to work.

Comment: I would rebuild the Spotlight index, as Spotlight needs to be working properly to return the correct information.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and recents now shows recent files in Finder window. However, the window that popups when uploading files to websites on a browser (safari/Firefox) doesn't show anything under recents tab.